# Prove that a sequence diverges if and only if its subsequence diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that $(x_n)_n$ diverges if and only if for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ for $(x_n)_n$ such that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $|{x_{n_k} - a}| \ge \epsilon$.

Thank you!

Comment: One direction of this ($\Leftarrow$) is *very* straightforward; have you any ideas on how to prove that direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a sequence diverges, then since it is a  subsequence of itself, it has a subsequence which diverges.

If a sequence converges, then every subsequence converges to the same  limit. Hence if you have a divergent subsequence, the sequence cannot converge.